# Jqgrid - Setting textarea programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, textarea

I have a functioning grid with form-based editing.  On the form I'd like to set the value of 'eventprocessor.configuration' based on the selection in 'rule.id'.

As you can see 'rule.id' has dataEvents to capture the value when it changes - this works and appears in the alert().  But I don't know how to set the value in 'eventprocessor.configuration'.

I have tried...

```
$('textarea#eventprocessor.configuration').val(this.value)
$('textarea#eventprocessor.configuration').html(this.value)
$('textarea#eventprocessor.configuration').text(this.value)
```

...but none of those work.

My code...

```
...

{
    name: 'rule.id', 
    index: 'rule.id', 
    editable: true, 
    edittype: 'select', 

    editoptions:
    {
        value: '<?php echo $rules; ?>', 
        defaultValue: 0, 
        dataEvents: [
            {
                type: 'change', 
                fn: function() {
                    alert(this.value);
                    $('textarea#eventprocessor.configuration').val(this.value)
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 

    editrules: {required: true}
}, 

{
    name: 'eventprocessor.configuration', 
    index: 'eventprocessor.configuration', 
    editable: true, 
    edittype: 'textarea', 
    editrules: {required: true}, 
    editoptions: {rows: 4}, 
    required: true
},

...
```

Code I've found by searching does not solve my problem even though it seems to for others.  What am I missing to set the value of the 'eventprocessor.configuration' based on 'rule.id'?

Many thanks.

Comment: try pulling it into a variable first? Something like `var textValue = this.value; $('textarea#eventprocessor.configuration').val(textValue);`. Also are you sure `eventprocessor.configuration` is the id of the textarea?

Comment: Your formal answered did the trick.  Yes, the id is in fact 'eventprocessor.configuration'.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of the fullstop in id of the text area. Try this:

```
$('#eventprocessor\\.configuration').text(this.value);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/meTnN/

Comment: Awesome, not a problem :)